# Hessian matrix of log marginal likelihood of Gaussian Process

Tags: gaussian-process, hyperparameter, hessian

I'm trying to compute the exact second derivatives of log marginal likelihood of Gaussian Process for learning hyperparameters.

The log marginal likelihood and its partial derivative are given in 5 chapter of GPML(http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf) as

$$
\log p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{X}, \theta) = -\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}^TK^{-1}_y \mathbf{y} -\dfrac{1}{2}\log|K_y| - \dfrac{n}{2}\log{2\pi} \tag{1}
$$

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \log p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{X}, \theta) = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{y}^T K^{-1} \dfrac{\partial K}{\partial \theta_j} K^{-1} \mathbf{y} - \dfrac{1}{2} tr(K^{-1} \dfrac{\partial K}{\partial \theta_j}) \tag{2}
$$
where

$K_y(x^p, x^q) = \sigma^2_f \exp(-\dfrac{1}{2l^2}(x_p - x_q)^T (x_p - x_q))
 + \sigma^2_n\delta_{pq}$,

$\theta = (l, \sigma_f, \sigma_n)$

---

refferring to [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf), I'm tackling with calculating the hessian matrix of $\log p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{\theta})$, 
but it's not easy for me to do.

Can you compute hessian matrix of $\log p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{\theta})$ by hand?